# Using JavaScript and jQuery in same file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I use JavaScript and jQuery side by side on the same file or element?

I heard that this is possible: why doesn't the code below work? If I get some element using jQuery(#) and then use `innerHTML` to change it, it doesn't work. So, for example,

```
<body>  
  <script> 
     $(function(){
     var b= $('#p');
     b.innerHTML="wow";
     });
  </script>
  <p id="p">hey</p>
</body>
```

Comment: jquery **IS** javascript. it's just a very handy set of tools written in javascript.

Comment: `b[0].innerHTML="wow";` the jquery function returns an array every time even if there is only one element.

Comment: If you mix them up, try to keep track of your jquery variables by prepending them with $, helps me a lot to know when to use which methods on vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a superset of JavaScript. It IS JavaScript! Just a neat tool set for JavaScript so widely used it's almost considered essential to many people.

That being said, jQuery selections are jQuery objects and have some specific properties. They aren't 100% compatible with normal DOM nodes. **It's best to stick with one or the other.** There are only rare cases where you need to use standard JavaScript anyway because jQuery has so many methods available to you. In this case use:

```
$(function(){
    var b= $('#p');
    b.text("wow");
});
```

If you really want to get the DOM node out of that you'll have to use the array reference which can give you the node, but this means that either you'll only effect the first element such as in this case:

```
$(function(){
    var b= $('#p');
    b[0].innerHTML = "wow";
});
```

or you'll have to loop through and change each element one by one like this:

```
$(function(){
    var b= $('#p');
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
       b[i].innerHTML = "wow";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a Javascript framework, so yes you can inherently use them together

```
var node = document.createElement('input'); //plain old javascript

$(node).click(function(){ alert('you set a click with jQuery') }); //here we are using jQuery

node.getAttribute('name'); //here we are using plain javascript again.
```

`$('#p')` will return an array of elements. if you want to check the innerHTML of them you have to iterate though them...or specify the element like this..

```
b[0].innerHTML = "wow"
```

Answer (score -1):

Because variable b is a jquery element and its html is set by

```
b.html("wow");
```

[More documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/) on .html().

Comment: This is so wrong. You're like re-assigning a method call.

Comment: I hv edited it...can be upvoted now

Comment: The b.html() would be used to get the text or whatever inside of the element. `var x = b.html();` In order to change it you need to use the `text` method i.e `b.text(x+"Adding stuff");` Or as of jquery 1.4 you can pass it in directly `x.html("stuff");`

Comment: Answer as edited is now correct.

Comment: This doesn't explain *why* the example code doesn't work. The OP is asking "Why doesn't this work? Can you not use jQuery and JavaScript together?" and you're replying with: "Just use jQuery."

Comment: ofcourse jquery and javascript can go together as jquery is written in javascript. I told him a solution that will work in this case, a jquery solution

Comment: downvoting on a correct answer should not be the resolution...

Comment: @V31 Maybe so, but this would be better phrased as a comment: it does not entirely answer the question.

Comment: @AstroCB: Since it is a solution thought of writing it as an answer, will give more insight over here to make it more understandable

Comment: @V31 Users are free to vote as they please, and clearly, I wasn't the only one who thought that this didn't entirely answer the question, as you can tell from the vote counts.